# A question about pushforward measures and continuous Borel isomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures, pushforward

It is fairly well known that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are nonatomic measures on the standard Borel spaces $(X,B)$ and $(Y,C)$ such that $\mu(X)=\nu(Y)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are uncountable, then there exists a Borel isomorphism $f : X \to Y$ such that $f_\# \mu=\nu$.

Keep in mind that if $(X,B)$ and $(Y,C)$ are measurable spaces, $f: X \to Y$ is a measurable map, and $\mu$ is a measure on $B$, then we write $f_\#\mu$ for the push forward measure on $C$, which is defined by $f_\#\mu(A) = \mu(f^{-1}(A))$ for all $A \in C$.

Is there a continuous analog for this? Specifically, considering that Borel isomorphisms need not be continuous, is there anything similar to the result above, but where $f$ is continuous?

Any insight would be valuable.